# c++ - Using zlib with const data

Tags: c++, casting, constants, zlib, stdvector

To compress/decompress data with zlib , first I need to set up a struct called `z_stream`.
`z_stream` has two non-const pointers called `next_in` and `next_out`.

If I want to do a function like this:

```
void ungzip(std::vector<unsigned char>& dst,const std::vector<unsigned char>& src)
{
  z_stream strm;
  // more code
}
```

and other like,

```
void gzip  (std::vector<unsigned char>& dst,const std::vector<unsigned char>& src);
```

What I should do?

Copy src in a local `std::vector<unsigned char>`

```
std::vector<unsigned char> tmp(src);
```

and use it as source or setting pointer like this , `strm.next_in = const_cast<char*>(&src[0])`?

Does zlib keep input data?

Comment: I would recommend accepting the input via iterators:  with this design, it constrains the caller to store the data in `vector<unsigned char>`

Comment: zlib does not touch the input data. It is treated as if it were `const`. `next_in` is not `const` by default since many applications use `next_in` outside of zlib to read in their data. Making it `const` would break those applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the cleanest way would be to just define `ZLIB_CONST` when compiling so that the input pointer is defined to be a `const unsigned char *` instead.

Note however that simply casting away const-ness is indeed going to work (it's legal if the character being pointed to is not actually constant).
The code for this should be:

```
strm.next_in = (unsigned char *)&src[0];
```

or the uglier `const_cast` variant if you are into that kind of things.

Note that default in `zlib` is NOT to have `ZLIB_CONST` defined and if you want to use a precompiled `zlib` binary the casting solution is the best option. You should go for the `ZLIB_CONST` solution only if you're compiling yourself the library too with the same define<sup>(1)</sup>.

---

(1) Giving the compiler an header with different semantic meaning is a bad idea - and a formal breaking of C++ standard rules - and it could - at least in theory - create protability problems.

With X86 architecture this is probably not the case and the library compiled with or without `ZLIB_CONST` would end up with the exact same bytes; however there are also different architectures.

For example I've been working with CPUs in which there were different pointer registers for different alignments. In that CPUs reading say an integer from an address that wasn't a multiple or 4 was an error generating an hardware trap (moreover something that at the time surprised me is that the error was triggered even by just assigning the pointer a non-aligned address, even if that misaligned address was never used for reading or writing).

With that compiler I didn't check (I was working only on high-level software) but I wouldn't be surprised if the system ABI specifed that a function `void foo(char *)` and `void bar(int *)` would have to receive the parameter in different registers.

More to the point, I never worked with but I can imagine may exist CPUs or VMs for which certain registers (let's name one as `RW0`) can be used for reading/writing operations and other registers (e.g. `R0`) can be used only for reading.
With such an architecture the ABI may specify that the first parameter of type `const char *` must be passed in `R0` and the first parameter of type `char *` must be passed in `RW0` instead.

If this is the case compiling a library with a function `void foo(char *p){...}` and then compiling the calling code using as declaration `void foo(const char *p);` would actually end up passing the address in the wrong register!

Comment: If I'm using the package provided by a Linux distro, shall I recomplile zlib just for my program?

Comment: @R.F.Luis: Then go for option 2: Just pass `(char *)&src[0]`; data in a `std::vector` cannot be const, it's safe to cast away const-ness.

Comment: src is a `const std::vector<unsigned char>&` so data must be `const` and needs to be casted using `const_cast`. If object is _const qualified_, you can't change it.

Comment: @R.F.Luis: the const-ness concept is slightly more complex than that and there is a difference between const data and const references. To be more specific the term `const` with a **reference** only expresses a property **of the reference** and tells nothing about the data being referenced: characters contained in an `std::vector` cannot be `const`... so it's always safe to cast away constness from a const reference bound to a vector.

Comment: I don't understand what do you refer.Following code  `#include <vector>`

`void sum(const std::vector<int>& data){
  if (data.size()>2) for (int i=1;i<data.size();i++) data[0]+=data[i];
  return;
  }` gives the following error when compiling with g++ `const-vector.cpp: In function ‘void sum(const std::vector<int>&)’:
const-vector.cpp:4:69: error: assignment of read-only location ‘(& data)->std::vector<int>::operator[](0)’
   if (data.size()>2) for (int i=1;i<data.size();i++) data[0]+=data[i];`

Comment: Sorry. This worked fine. `void sum(const std::vector<int>& data){
  int *ptr;
  ptr = (int*) &data[0];
  if (data.size()>2) for (int i=1;i<data.size();i++) ptr[0]+=ptr[i];
  return;
  }`

Comment: > If I'm using the package provided by a Linux distro, shall I recomplile zlib just for my program?

I believe that you don't have to recompile zlib to use ZLIB_CONST; you only need to `#define ZLIB_CONST` before `#include <zlib.h>` in your code.

Comment: @MikeKaganski: that may practically work but it's a violation of the C++ standard. For example (from a formal point of view) you cannot compile a library with `foo(char *p)` and then using it with an header with `foo(const char *p)`. Even if you're avoiding the name mangling problems (because it's `extern "C"`) still you're using different definitions in different compile units for the same entity and this is not allowed. Casting away const is easier and formally valid for C++ standard (and it's even "philosophically" totally correct despite what some misinformed "const zealots" may think).

Comment: @6502 thanks - and that's a valid concern - but then how does one learn if ZLIB_CONST was defined or not in the library itself when linking from own code to e.g. pre-compiled library? One only can hope that it was default... ;) It seems to had introduced an unconditional UB.

Comment: @MikeKaganski: pre-compiled libraries with compile options that change the library interface are indeed a problem, and just one of the many of distributing (or sharing!) binaries in general. In C++ creating a true barrier between interface and implementation and providing ABI stability (and not just API stability "recompile-EVERYTHING-and-it-will-work") requires quite some effort; the language was not designed with this in mind; most of these failures also are subtle and in the "UB, no diagnostic required" area. Even passing an `std::string` to a binary library means looking for troubles.

Comment: Defining `ZLIB_CONST` when building zlib is _not_ the default. See my comment on the question. There is no way to tell what it was compiled with, but it doesn't matter. All uses of `z_const` can be treated as `const`, since the zlib code will never modify what is at those pointers.

Comment: @MarkAdler Added a note that `ZLIB_CONST` is not the default, and a deeper explanation of why casting is better that just compiling the client code with a different prototype (even if on x86 this may work too).

Comment: "I can imagine may exist CPUs or VMs for which certain registers ... can be used for reading/writing operations and other registers ... can be used only for reading."

Just a note that the define in question is unrelated to this possible architecture specialties, since the define changes the definition (and potentially the layout) of a (member in a) struct, not some calling convention.

Comment: @MikeKaganski: I'm not sure I understand your point. The `#define` changes the signature of a function pointer; I'm saying that if the signature is different it's not just that the value may be in the wrong format, but that it can also be passed in a different register. Consider `void foo(double)` and `void bar(unsigned long long)` on x86-64; the ABI tells that in `foo` the arg must be passed in a register and in `bar` a different one. Even if the implementation e.g. just uses memcpy to store the bits passed (ignoring their meaning) things are not going to work if using the wrong declaration.

Comment: "The `#define` changes the signature of a function pointer" - where? The `#define` changes the signature of *struct members* - specifically, `z_stream_s::next_in`, `z_stream_s::msg` in `zlib.h`. Ah, I see now that it *also* is used there in `typedef unsigned (*in_func)` ... yes, that's different to what I was talking about.